# Checkbox in ASP.NET MVC controller to convert into bit

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a scenario in ASP.NET MVC where in one table in my database, a row contains a column `Active` (bit); how to update the row in ASP.NET MVC using a checkbox?

If it's checked, then the value must be 1, if not, it must take 0 - how to do this? Can anyone please help here?

Please help me out by model view and controller script without using Entity Framework.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve] of your progress so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

`.cshtml code`

```
@model Model

@for(var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
    Html.CheckBoxFor(m => model[i].Active)
}
```

now this will bind the checkbox in a `hiddenfield` that will update the model if `checked = true or false`, then your model will have value of `.Active true or false` depending on the checked value

Answer (score 0):

The default method `checkbox.Checked()` returns `true` or `false`. If you update your row with the true or false, sql auto converts this to 1 or 0, 1 being true and 0 being false.